# Bootstrap Carousel only on home page

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a Website using Bootstrap 4.  The template that I am using has a carousel at the top of the page.  I use my index.php page as a shell for other content which is called using the following code:

```
    <?php 
        if (!isset($_REQUEST['content']))
                include("home.php");                    
        else
        {
                $content = $_REQUEST['content'];
                $nextpage = $content;
                include($nextpage);
        }
    ?>
```

Currently the carousel will show on every page.  I would like for it to only show on the home page or index.phpcontent=home.php but I have yet to figure out how to do that without breaking things.

On the index.php page I have set up chunks of code to be called with include statements:

```
<body>
   <header>
     <?php include 'navbar.php'; ?>  
     <?php include 'carousel.php'; ?>
   </header>
```

I have tried to programatically simply call the carousel.php as follows:

```
    <?php 
        if (!isset($_REQUEST['content']))
                include("carousel.php");                    
        else
        {
                include("");
        }
    ?>
```

But that did not work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is your $_REQUEST['content']?

Comment: The content says that if there is something include the home content else include the content that is passed in the link EX - <a class="footer" target="_self" href="index.php?content=contact-us.php" target="_blank">Contact Us</a>

Comment: then you want to include carsoul when content is exist else no ?